# Easy Split Layout Plugin For jQuery - Splitter drag event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, splitter

Has anybody used the Easy Split Layout Plugin For jQuery as shown [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Split-Layout-Plugin-jQuery-Splitter.html)?
The ondrag, ondragstart, and ondragend events only fire once when the plugin is initialized.  After that, nothing.

Here is my code:

```
function setSplitters() {
   $('#widget').width(1500).height(768).split({ //left container
       orientation: 'vertical', 
       limit: 150,
       position: '20%',
       onDrag: console.log("dragging..."),   
       onDragStart: console.log("dragging has started"),
       onDragEnd: console.log("dragging has ended")
   });
```

When I refresh the browser (chrome), I see the three console.log outputs but when I drag the splitter bar, nothing.

Here are the dependencies:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.splitter.js"></script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works in fiddle:

I used:
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.splitter@0.28.5/js/jquery.splitter.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.splitter@0.28.5/css/jquery.splitter.css
and
JQuery 3.4.1

HTML

```html
<div id="widget">
    <div id="leftPane">Foo</div>
    <div id="rightPane">Bar</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
function setSplitters() {
   var splitter = $('#widget').width(1500).height(768).split({
    orientation: 'vertical',
    limit: 150,
    position: '20%',
    onDrag: function(event) {
      console.log(splitter.position());
    },
    onDragStart: console.log("dragging has started"),
    onDragEnd: console.log("dragging has ended")
  });
}

setSplitters();
```

Gives the position in console.log if you drag the divider

Comment: Thank you!  Sure would be nice if they'd provide documentation.